# Measuring Event Differences in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I've started rolling out new features to a site using Netlify's branch split testing so I can say ex. 10% of users gets a branch with a specific UI change to see if it produces measurably different results. I have google analytics events set up to track some useful metrics already.

**How can I compare the events in branch A with branch B in google analytics?** I think there are two parts here: how to change the analytics code to identify sessions on branch A vs branch B, and also where to create a view in google analytics that I can compare events from sessions in A to sessions in B.

I'm happy with the tools I'm using so I'd like to avoid cluttering my page with yet another tracking script from a single-purpose A/B test provider when I'm pretty sure my existing tools can do this, I just don't know how.

Comment: Netlify suggests using a custom dimension: https://www.netlify.com/docs/split-testing/#branch-split-testing -- does that work for you? And are you using Google Tag Manager or do you include GA directly?

Comment: @Reve that's what I ended up with yeah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more experimentation, I figured out what I was looking for:

Netlify adds an environmental variable `BRANCH` that tells you what portion of the A/B test you're on. I created a new dimension in google analytics and used my analytics tags to set `dimension4: process.env.BRANCH`.

To compare against normal traffic in google analytics, I created a fresh segment that was based off my new dimension, matching the branch name exactly. Now I can compare traffic or events on any screen that can compare between segments.

Comment: can you detailed your process to create your dimension and get the data in a segment on Analytics. I added the following code on our branches:
`ga('send', 'pageview', { 'Branch': 'branch-name' });` I created a personalized dimension in analytics named 'branch-name' but I don't see any data when looking at this dimension in my report. Did I forget any steps?

Comment: The key name isn't `Branch`, it's `dimension4` or whichever dimension number you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has built in support for multivariate A/B testing. The first is available within GA under "Behavior" -> "Experiments." The second way to do this is via [Google Optimize](https://www.google.com/analytics/optimize/).

I'm not sure how these would work with the A/B testing solution you are already using but it will provide a great way to compare analytic performance between the different versions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Optimize seems like an interesting and easy to use tool for testing text changes and other cosmetic edits on a page - netlify A/B gets a bit more powerful since I can deploy code base changes.